# rails s を実行するとポート3000がすでに使用されているため、Pumaサーバーが起動できない

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
rails s
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 7.0.3.1 application starting in development 
=> Run `bin/rails server --help` for more startup options
Puma starting in single mode...
* Puma version: 5.6.4 (ruby 3.1.4-p223) ("Birdie's Version")
*  Min threads: 5
*  Max threads: 5
*  Environment: development
*          PID: 232
Exiting
/usr/local/bundle/gems/puma-5.6.4/lib/puma/binder.rb:341:in `initialize': Address already in use - bind(2) for "127.0.0.1" port 3000 (Errno::EADDRINUSE)
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/puma-5.6.4/lib/puma/binder.rb:341:in `new'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/puma-5.6.4/lib/puma/binder.rb:341:in `add_tcp_listener'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/puma-5.6.4/lib/puma/binder.rb:335:in `block in add_tcp_listener'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/puma-5.6.4/lib/puma/binder.rb:334:in `each'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/puma-5.6.4/lib/puma/binder.rb:334:in `add_tcp_listener'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/puma-5.6.4/lib/puma/binder.rb:173:in `block in parse'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/puma-5.6.4/lib/puma/binder.rb:156:in `each'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/puma-5.6.4/lib/puma/binder.rb:156:in `parse'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/puma-5.6.4/lib/puma/runner.rb:156:in `load_and_bind'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/puma-5.6.4/lib/puma/single.rb:44:in `run'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/puma-5.6.4/lib/puma/launcher.rb:182:in `run'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/puma-5.6.4/lib/rack/handler/puma.rb:72:in `run'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-2.2.4/lib/rack/server.rb:327:in `start'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-7.0.3.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:38:in `start'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-7.0.3.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:143:in `block in perform'
    from <internal:kernel>:90:in `tap'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-7.0.3.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:134:in `perform'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-7.0.3.1/lib/rails/command/base.rb:87:in `perform'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-7.0.3.1/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-7.0.3.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.12.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.12.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

下記を実行しても変わリません

```
 lsof -i :3000
COMMAND PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
ruby      1 root    6u  IPv4 107994      0t0  TCP *:3000 (LISTEN)
root@ab61f30e2e50:/v3_basic_rails_basic# sudo kill -9 1
```

ここでずっと手こずってしまい前に進まない状態です。。。

Comment: 恐らく Docker コンテナで作業しているように見えますが、もう少し詳しい情報を記載しておくと回答が付きやすいと思います。

Answer (score 0):

3000 番ポートを使っているプロセスの PID が 1 になっており、これは特別な PID なので `kill` コマンドによる SIGKILL シグナルが無視されています。

おそらく何らかの Docker イメージの上で作業なさっているのだと思われますが、TTY を繋いで何か作業することが想定されたイメージというよりかはアプリとして立ち上げることが想定されたイメージで作業なさっていないでしょうか。Dockerfile か `docker inspect` で ENTRYPOINT や CMD を確認してみてください。そして別の適切なイメージを使うようにしてみてください。